# Как происходит сортировка, если параметр в OrderBy равен null?

Tags: c#, linq

Есть вот такой код:

```
var ctx = new MyBD();
var data = ctx.Employee.AsNoTracking().Where(x => 
x.id_employee == id_employee).OrderBy(x=>x.sort_id).ToList();
```

Мой вопрос кроется в непонимании, что происходит внутри сортировки, так как код работает при всех (моих) возможных случаях:

1. Все значения null.
2. Числа и null.
3. Все числа.

При всех случаях метод срабатывает и я получаю все значения. Никакой ошибки.

Comment: Судя по коду это запрос к базе данных, поэтому сортировка будет выполнятся базой данных, и соответственно как она работает с null тоже зависит от того, какая это БД (а в вопросе это не указано). Обычно либо сначала идут NULL а потом отсортированные значения, либо наоборот (NULL в конце).

Comment: Невозможно точно ответить на этот вопрос, не зная следующее: используемые СУБД, ORM и провайдер.

Comment: Кажется, автор вопроса путает сортировку с фильтрацией. Это вообще тут частый случай в вопросах на SO. Сортировка `OrderBy` не может "не сработать" и что-то не выдать из выборки. Она **сортирует**, т.е. меняет (или не меняет) порядок следования элементов. Если ключ сортировки константа, то просто порядок элементов никак не поменяется (если в `Linq` используется "устойчивая сортировка", а скорее всего именно она и используется). Вот фильтрация `Where` - она может отсеять какие-то элементы, если условие не выполнится.

Comment: Такие штуки можно тестировать самостоятельно, я считаю

Comment: @aepot Я потестировал, получил значения при разных комбинациях. В итоге были предположения, что там внутри происходит (в принципе, в комментариях они и были озвучены). Но я хотел узнать точно, что на самом деле происходит.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov MS SQL, entity framework.